# Is it usual to create a parent POM for different projects?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

I have three different multimodule projects. I have also created one POM in the top level folder of these three different projects where I have added some configuration such as `dependencyManagement` element. So the different projects have their parent element set to this POM.

I wonder if such usage is a little strange or bad? Should I delete this POM and instead configure each top level POM of each multimodule project?

Answer (score 1):

It's not unusual at all. [Parent](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html#pom-relationships-sect-project-inheritance) and multi-module projects [are not the same thing](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit), so by all means you can reuse your config the way you described. In fact, [that's how all projects in Maven work, in a sense](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom.html#fig-super-always-base).

However, if I understand you correctly, you have a "meta-parent" sitting in a folder that contains several of the child projects, which are multi-module themselves. This might be confusing since it evokes association with modules (which the children are not). You might be slightly better-of having the "meta-parent" sit in a folder parallel to the multi-module projects, have the `relativePath` of the latter set to `../metaParent`, and/or deploy the "meta-parent" to your Maven repo.